# pointer to array of ints c++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, reference

I wrote the following code to try to understand how we can use pointers to arrays and references to arrays. Here is my thought process of what is happening.

1. `arr` is the same as the address of the first elements of the array. `*arr` gives me what is the int at that location as does `arr[0]`.
2. `p` is a pointer and gets assigned `arr` which is the address of the first element. So in essence `*p` is the same as `*arr` and `p[0]` is the same as `arr[0]`.
3. Here i don't understand what is happening. `arrPtr` is a pointer to an array of ten integers. Why doesn't `*arrPtr` or `arrPtr[0]` yield me the value 9?
4. `arrRef` is a reference to an array of ten integers and unlike in the point above `*arrRef` or `arrRef[0]` does yield value 9.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main() {
    int arr[10] = {9, 18, 31, 40, 42};
    cout << "arr: " << arr << endl;
    cout << "*arr: " << *arr << endl;
    cout << "arr[0]: " << arr[0] << endl;
    cout << endl;

    int *p = arr;
    cout << "p: " << p << endl;
    cout << "*p: " << *p << endl;
    cout << "p[0]: " << p[0] << endl;
    cout << endl;

    int (*arrPtr)[10] = &arr;
    cout << "arrPtr: " << arrPtr << endl;
    cout << "*arrPtr: " << *arrPtr << endl;
    cout << "arrPtr[0]: " << arrPtr[0] << endl;
    cout << endl;

    int (&arrRef)[10] = arr;
    cout << "arrRef: " << arrRef << endl;
    cout << "*arrRef: " << *arrRef << endl;
    cout << "arrRef[0]: " << arrRef[0] << endl;
}
```

Here is my output:

```
arr: 0xbf843e28
*arr: 9
arr[0]: 9

p: 0xbf843e28
*p: 9
p[0]: 9

arrPtr: 0xbf843e28
*arrPtr: 0xbf843e28
arrPtr[0]: 0xbf843e28

arrRef: 0xbf843e28
*arrRef: 9
arrRef[0]: 9
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`*arrPtr` or `arrPtr[0]` yields an object of the type `int[10]`

Used in the `operator <<` the array is explicitly converted to pointer of type `int *` and the overloaded `operator <<` for the parameter of `const void *` is selected for such an expression.

You can see that these outputs

```
arr: 0xbf843e28
```

and

```
*arrPtr: 0xbf843e28
arrPtr[0]: 0xbf843e28
```

coincide.

If you want to output the first element of the array you should write either

```
std::cout << **arrPtr << std::endl;
std::cout << ( *arrPtr )[0] << std::endl;
std::cout << arrPtr[0][0] << std::endl;
std::cout << *arrPtr[0] << std::endl;
```

To make it more clear you can introduce a reference such a way

```
int ( &arrRef )[10] = *arrPtr;
```

and then write

```
std::cout << *arrRef << std::endl;
std::cout << arrRef[0] << std::endl;
```